# OnItemClickListener показывает текст исключительно с последнего элемента списка

Tags: java, android

Есть кастомный элемент списка в котором textview. Выводит,исключительно,текст из ПОСЛЕДНЕГО элемента списка, вне зависимости он кликнутой позиции.

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            hideDialog();
            //parsing json
            try{
                JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("image_info_table");
                for(int i=0;i<obj.length();i++){
                    final JSONObject info = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                    final Item item=new Item();
                    item.setTitle(info.getString("name"));
                    item.setImage(info.getString("path"));
                    array.add(item);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
                            System.out.println("itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
                                    + id);
                            System.out.println( item.getTitle());\\ проблемка вот тут, выводит текст, только из нижнего, последнего элемента списка.
                        }

                    });

                }
```

Подскажите,плз, как реализовать корректную работу по выводу текста с каждого элемента списка, а не только из  последнего.

Comment: Парсить JSON руками - извращение. Используйте Gson

Comment: Спасибо, изучу эту библиотеку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы загоняете последний 'Item ' в массив, а потом при клике на любой элемент списка выводите текст из этого последнего 'Item'.

В Вашем случае в 'Listener'-e должен был быть код примерно такой:

```
System.out.println(array.get(position).getTitle());
```

Установку 'Listener'-а кстати вынесите из цикла, а то постоянно его перезаписываете.

Answer (score 2):

Вы каждый раз перезаписываете onItemClickListener, в конечном итоге остаётся только последний.

Вот одно из решений:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    hideDialog();
    //parsing json
    try{
        JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("image_info_table");
        if (obj != null) { 
            for (int i=0;i<obj.length();i++){ 
                 final Item item = new Item();
                 item.setTitle(info.getString("name"));
                 item.setImage(info.getString("path"));
                 array.add(item);
            } 
        } 

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
                   System.out.println("itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = " + id);
                   System.out.println(array.get(position).getTitle());
             }
         });
 }
```